# counting number of times a particular level and then aggregating it the number of times in new variable

Tags: sql

Counting number of times a particular level (in transaction data) and then aggregating it the number of times in new variable (under one row per customer)

[image]

I have 2 levels to solicitation method, phone and email. I have created 2 new columns which count the number of times phone or email happened per id. Right now I have transaction data and cant figure out how to go about it. the data is on left, what I want is on right. I am okay with both kinds of output on right side. 
So far I tried this. returns error

```
create table d.email as
select ID, email_count  
from d.emai
where email_count = (select count (*) 
                     from d.email
                     group by ID
                     having SolicitMethod = 'Email' );
quit;
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: Can you run the sub-query stand-alone? How many rows does it return?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want to do, but you can fix the syntax error by making the subquery a correlated subquery:

```
create table d.email as
    select ID, email_count  
    from d.emai e
    where email_count = (select count(*) 
                         from d.email e2
                         where  e2.SolicitMethod = 'Email' and e2.id = e.id
                        );
```

I assume the reference in the first `from` should be `d.emai`.

Answer (score 0):

The first output can be obtain with this query:

*It groups rows by id, and then count how many rows are on each SolicitMethod*

```
SELECT id
     , SUM(CASE
               WHEN SolicitMethod = 'Email' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END) count_email
     , SUM(CASE
               WHEN SolicitMethod = 'phone' THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END) count_phone
FROM   d.email
GROUP  BY id
```

This second output query depends of your dbms and availability of analytics function:

*it count on each rows the count of sollicitMethod of each group of id*

```
 SELECT id
         , SUM(CASE
                   WHEN SolicitMethod = 'Email' THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END)
               OVER (partition BY id) count_email
         , SUM(CASE
                   WHEN SolicitMethod = 'phone' THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END)
               OVER (partition BY id) count_phone
    FROM   d.email
```

Comment: Yes the first part works. Thanks. Saved tonnes of time.